# looking for a more efficient way to create a dataframe than looping in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table/dataframe based on the AcceptanceSampling library as follows:

```
library(AcceptanceSampling)
df<-NULL
for (aql in c(0.01,0.05)){
for (prp in c(0.95)) {
for (def in c(0.06,0.1,0.15)){
for (crp in c(0.05,0.08,0.10)){
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(df,c(aql,prp,def,crp,
                         find.plan(PRP=c(aql,prp),CRP=c(def,crp))$n,
                         find.plan(PRP=c(aql,prp),CRP=c(def,crp))$c
                         )))
}}}}

names(df)<-c("aql","prp","def","crp","n","Ac")
```

this gives me:

```
    aql  prp  def  crp    n  Ac
1  0.01 0.95 0.06 0.05  127   3
2  0.01 0.95 0.06 0.08  116   3
3  0.01 0.95 0.06 0.10  110   3
4  0.01 0.95 0.10 0.05   61   2
5  0.01 0.95 0.10 0.08   55   2
6  0.01 0.95 0.10 0.10   52   2
7  0.01 0.95 0.15 0.05   30   1
8  0.01 0.95 0.15 0.08   27   1
9  0.01 0.95 0.15 0.10   25   1
10 0.05 0.95 0.06 0.05 5626 308
11 0.05 0.95 0.06 0.08 4826 266
12 0.05 0.95 0.06 0.10 4445 246
13 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.05  298  21
14 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.08  251  18
15 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.10  233  17
16 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.05   93   8
17 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.08   79   7
18 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.10   77   7
```

Can someone point to a more efficient way to build this ?  Preferably without the loops and without having to call find.plan() twice for each row ?

Thanks in advance
Pete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative answer using base R functions:

```
install.packages("AcceptanceSampling")
library(AcceptanceSampling)

df <- expand.grid(
  aql = c(0.01,0.05),
  prp = c(0.95),
  def = c(0.06,0.1,0.15),
  crp = c(0.05,0.08,0.10)
)

findpl <- do.call(
  rbind,
  by(df,df,function(x) {
    i <- find.plan(c(x$aql,x$prp),c(x$def,x$crp))
    c(n=i$n,Ac=i$c)
    }
  )
)

result <- data.frame(df,findpl)

head(result)

   aql  prp  def  crp    n  Ac
1 0.01 0.95 0.06 0.05  127   3
2 0.05 0.95 0.06 0.05 5626 308
3 0.01 0.95 0.10 0.05   61   2
4 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.05  298  21
5 0.01 0.95 0.15 0.05   30   1
6 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.05   93   8
```

Comment: Selected this answer compared to @agstudy only because I find it a bit easier to understand. Both excellent. Much appreciated, and many thanks to you both. Pete

Answer (score 5):

You can use `expand.grid` like this :

```
dat <- expand.grid(aql = c(0.01,0.05),prp = c(0.95),
            def = c(0.06,0.1,0.15), crp = c(0.05,0.08,0.10))
```

Then using `data.table` for each syntax sugar:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[, c('n','Ac') := list(find.plan(PRP=c(aql,prp),CRP=c(def,crp))$n,
                         find.plan(PRP=c(aql,prp),CRP=c(def,crp))$c),
                           by = 1:nrow(DT)]

    aql  prp  def  crp    n  Ac
 1: 0.01 0.95 0.06 0.05  127   3
 2: 0.05 0.95 0.06 0.05 5626 308
 3: 0.01 0.95 0.10 0.05   61   2
 4: 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.05  298  21
 5: 0.01 0.95 0.15 0.05   30   1
 6: 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.05   93   8
 7: 0.01 0.95 0.06 0.08  116   3
 8: 0.05 0.95 0.06 0.08 4826 266
 9: 0.01 0.95 0.10 0.08   55   2
10: 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.08  251  18
11: 0.01 0.95 0.15 0.08   27   1
12: 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.08   79   7
13: 0.01 0.95 0.06 0.10  110   3
14: 0.05 0.95 0.06 0.10 4445 246
15: 0.01 0.95 0.10 0.10   52   2
16: 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.10  233  17
17: 0.01 0.95 0.15 0.10   25   1
18: 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.10   77   7
```

**EDIT** using base functions, the idea is to vectorize `find.plan`. Here I am using `mapply` like this:

```
 cbind(dat,with(dat,t(mapply(function(x,y,z,t)
                 find.plan(c(x,y),c(z,t)),aql,prp,def,crp))))

  aql  prp  def  crp    n   c   r
1  0.01 0.95 0.06 0.05  127   3   4
2  0.05 0.95 0.06 0.05 5626 308 309
3  0.01 0.95 0.10 0.05   61   2   3
4  0.05 0.95 0.10 0.05  298  21  22
5  0.01 0.95 0.15 0.05   30   1   2
6  0.05 0.95 0.15 0.05   93   8   9
7  0.01 0.95 0.06 0.08  116   3   4
8  0.05 0.95 0.06 0.08 4826 266 267
9  0.01 0.95 0.10 0.08   55   2   3
10 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.08  251  18  19
11 0.01 0.95 0.15 0.08   27   1   2
12 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.08   79   7   8
13 0.01 0.95 0.06 0.10  110   3   4
14 0.05 0.95 0.06 0.10 4445 246 247
15 0.01 0.95 0.10 0.10   52   2   3
16 0.05 0.95 0.10 0.10  233  17  18
17 0.01 0.95 0.15 0.10   25   1   2
18 0.05 0.95 0.15 0.10   77   7   8
```

Comment: This doesn't match up with the results requested. There needs to be a calculation of `find.plan` using the values in each row of `dat` rather than calling all at once.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks. I edit my answer. I assumed that `find.plan` is vectorized.